# CodeIgniter Upload Class - unique name for all files

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, continuous-integration

First - piece of codeigniter contoller where im uploading files:

```
        $files = $_FILES;
        $order_number = 5 //example
        $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

        $rand = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

        for($i=0;$i<$cpt;$i++)
        {
            if(!empty($files['userfile']['name'][$i]))
            {
                $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];    

                $format=explode('.',$files['userfile']['name'][$i]);
                $format=end($format);

                $config_img['upload_path'] = './uploads/orders';
                $config_img['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
                $config_img['file_name'] = $order_number.'_'.$rand.'.'.$format;
                $config_img['max_size'] = '5120';
(...)//some code that is not a problem
$this->load->library('upload', $config_img);
if($this->upload->do_upload())
(...)
```

Okay. Gettin files to this point works but saving it up with another name is problem. 
Fore expample i send file1.png and file2.jpg
And im not gettin 5_123123123.png and 5_864192696219.jpg and thats the problem.
Im gettin 2 files named same (only upload class add "1" before) but the biggest problem is that they have also same format. (.png in this example) my question is how can i get unique name here? Why its gettin for all files the same name?

Comment: put `$rand` inside the loop, its only set once

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens because of the cached configuration.Instead of passing the $config as a parameter you can reinitialize the new config using

$this->upload->initialize($config);
hope this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

put `$rand = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));` inside ur for loop